# HtmlAgilityPack replace node

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to replace a node with a new node. How can I get the exact position of the node and do a complete replace?

I've tried the following, but I can't figured out how to get the index of the node or which parent node to call `ReplaceChild()` on.

```
string html = "<b>bold_one</b><strong>strong</strong><b>bold_two</b>";
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);

var bolds = document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(item => item.Name == "b");

foreach (var item in bolds)
{

    string newNodeHtml = GenerateNewNodeHtml();
    HtmlNode newNode = new HtmlNode(HtmlNodeType.Text, document, ?);
    item.ParentNode.ReplaceChild( )
}
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To create a new node, use the `HtmlNode.CreateNode()` factory method, do not use the constructor directly.

This code should work out for you:

```
var htmlStr = "<b>bold_one</b><strong>strong</strong><b>bold_two</b>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlStr);

var query = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("b");
foreach (var item in query.ToList())
{
    var newNodeStr = "<foo>bar</foo>";
    var newNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode(newNodeStr);
    item.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode, item);
}
```

Note that we need to call `ToList()` on the query, we will be modifying the document so it would fail if we don't.

---

If you wish to replace with this string:

```
"some text <b>node</b> <strong>another node</strong>"
```

The problem is that it is no longer a single node but a series of nodes.  You can parse it fine using `HtmlNode.CreateNode()` but in the end, you're only referencing the first node of the sequence.  You would need to replace using the parent node.

```
var htmlStr = "<b>bold_one</b><strong>strong</strong><b>bold_two</b>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlStr);

var query = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("b");
foreach (var item in query.ToList())
{
    var newNodesStr = "some text <b>node</b> <strong>another node</strong>";
    var newHeadNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode(newNodesStr);
    item.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newHeadNode.ParentNode, item);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to replace a node with multiple other nodes? Example, if `newNodeStr='some text <b>node</b> <strong>another node</strong>'`, the replace doesn't work.

Comment: @Omar: Updated.  If you parse that string using `HtmlNode.CreateNode()`, it will result in creating a reference to the first node.  So if you replaced with that, you'd only see the first one being replaced.  You should actually be replacing the `ParentNode` to grab all of them.

Comment: After thinking about it, it might be safe to just always use `ParentNode` since a new, single node's parent is effectively itself when doing replacements.

Comment: this wont work if item has multiple tags eg. <em><strong>test</strong></em>

Comment: @Jason: Sure it does... did you actually _try_ it?

Comment: @JeffMercado Yes, but I think its just my code as crazy as it sounds I am getting different result while debugging anyway thanks for your quick response

Comment: "_Note that we need to call `ToList()` on the query, we will be modifying the document so it would fail if we don't._"
Statement was the very useful part for me.
Thanks.

Comment: I also find that CreateNode does not create sub-nodes - If I have "blah blah <p>foo bar</p>" then it truncates it to "blah blah" with no nested p tag. Same with "blah blah <br>" - leaves out the <br>. I had to swap out my code with HtmlDocument.LoadHtml. But I'm sure it used to work - maybe a debug/compile quirk.

Comment: @Etherman: As stated in the answer, `CreateNode()` will return _a_ node. That is a _series_ of nodes (a text node followed by an HTML node). Using `CreateNode()`, you'll obtain a reference to the first node, but you'll need to use the parent node to access the rest.

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean...I just assumed it would return the topmost root node of whatever it created, not something inside it...never even occurred to me to start looking UP the tree...seems an odd design choice to me!

Comment: @JeffMercado I have a problem replacing child tags with the text. I need to replace <p> with double new line and <div> with single. "<p><div>Das geilste Rasierwasser ever.</div></P>". 

`htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name != "#text" && n.Name != "#document").ToList()` returns two elements.
After the <p> is replaced, on the second iteraion the item.ParentNode is null. Do you know how I can handle it? Thank you

Comment: @JeffMercado The function to replace for <p>. Div Handler does the same besides 1 NL
        `private static void SurroundWithDoubleLineBreak(HtmlNode node)
        {
            var text = Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + node.InnerHtml + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode(text).ParentNode, node);
        }`

Comment: Still helpful 10 years later and worked perfectly for me. +1

Answer (score -1):

Have Implemented the following solution to achieve the same.

```
var htmlStr = "<b>bold_one</b><div class='LatestLayout'><div class='olddiv'><strong>strong</strong></div></div><b>bold_two</b>";
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
    document.Load(htmlStr);

htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='olddiv']").Remove();
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='LatestLayout']").PrependChild(newChild)

htmlDoc.Save(FilePath); // FilePath .html file with full path if need to save file.
```

so selecting an object and removing respective HTML object

and appending it as chile. of respective object.