# Add a link to a image with HtmlAgilityPack in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, html-agility-pack

I want to add a link to every image in the HTML with the value of the "href" attribute be the "src" attribute of the image. Namely changing the

```
 "<p> <img src="test.jpg"/></p>"
```

to

```
<p><a href="test.jpg"><img src="jpg"/></a></p>
```

And my code coming:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
var imgs = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img");
foreach (HtmlNode node in imgs)
{
    if (node.ParentNode.Name != "a")
    {
        string replaceStr = string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", node.GetAttributeValue("src", null), node.OuterHtml);
        //node.OuterHtml= replaceStr;   It doesn't work, the outerHtml is readonly
        //node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node, true);
    }
}
```

So how should I modify my code to make it work?

Updated:
after updating my code:

```
var imgs = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img");
            foreach (var node in imgs)
            {
                if (node.ParentNode.Name != "a")
                {
                    var a = document.CreateElement("a");
                    a.SetAttributeValue("href", node.GetAttributeValue("src", null));
                    a.ChildNodes.Add(node);
                    node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(a, node);
                }
            }
```

An error shows up "Unhandled InvalidOperationException ".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could use xpath to select `<img>` nodes whose parent node is not `<a>`:

```
var imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[not(parent::a)]").ToList();
```

Then you should iterate over these nodes. On each iteration step just create a new '' element, appent iteration '' to it, and then replace this '' with newly created `<a>`:

```
foreach (var img in imgs)
{
    var a = doc.CreateElement("a");
    a.SetAttributeValue("href", img.GetAttributeValue("src", null));
    a.ChildNodes.Add(img);
    img.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(a, img);
}
```

Comment: @ellic, could you post your html snippet?

Comment: the HTML snippet is at http://notepad.cc/veableosa97. It seems that there is something wrong with the "foreach()"

Comment: @ellic, sure the collection should be materialized first. See updated answer

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Problem solved after I updated the  HtmlAgilityPack for Windows Phone

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
string replaceStr = string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", node.GetAttributeValue("src", null), node.OuterHtml);
var newNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode(replaceStr);
node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode.ParentNode, node);
```

and change

```
foreach (var node in imgs)
```

by

```
foreach (var node in imgs.ToList())
```

[HtmlAgilityPack replace node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782500/htmlagilitypack-replace-node)