# Replace text inside div tag

Tags: c#, html, .net, regex, winforms

I have this HTML code

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="sidebar">
        My Sidebar Stuff

        <div id="Some Other Div"> 
            etc...
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Is it somehow possible to replace all the content inside the **SIDEBAR** div, including other divs, texts etc... I already tried some rudimentary Regex but i'm not that good at it.

Comment: See also [HtmlAgilityPack replace node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782500/htmlagilitypack-replace-node).

Comment: Parsing HTML with Regex is a bad idea.  There are other ways to manipulate the DOM

Answer (score 1):

Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (available from NuGet) for manipulation on HTML:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("index.html");
var sidebar = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='sidebar']");
sidebar.InnerHtml = "New Content!";
```